# error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity .addPackage(new ReactDatePackage(this))

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I want to use this module https://github.com/nucleartux/react-native-date for react-native. I trying to install this module, but when I do step 4 (Register React Package) I have an error with build.
Error message:

> MainActivity.java:31: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity
>   .addPackage(new ReactDatePackage(this))
>                                                    ^
>   Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
>   1 error
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed.

Code with error:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.facebook.react.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import me.nucleartux.date.ReactDatePackage;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements

DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new ReactDatePackage(this))
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "myapp", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
    mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
  } else {
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
}

@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this);
    }
}
}
```

Can you help me to fix this problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

In [the doc at step 4](https://github.com/nucleartux/react-native-date#step-4---register-react-package), you also have to make your `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler { // ! extends from FragmentActivity
```

(yours only extend `Activity`)

Comment: It's not helps for me.

Comment: Can you edit your post with those modifications ? :) Are you sure you rebuilt your app with `react-native run-android`?